# Is it necessary to put sleep() method in a try block while not catching the InterruptedException?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, interrupt

Here's the code:

```
List<BigInteger> aSecondOfPrimes() throws InterruptedException {
    PrimeGenerator generator = new PrimeGenerator();
    new Thread(generator).start();
    try {
        SECONDS.sleep(1);
    } finally {
        generator.cancel();
    }
    return generator.get();
}
```

As the method just throws the 'InterruptedException' while not catching it, is it necessary to put `SECONDS.sleep(1)` in a try block?

Comment: Depends on the 'finally' block. If you need it, then yes, no otherwise.

Comment: Only if you want that `finally`.

Comment: @Tom @SotiriosDelimanolis So if there is no `try block`, when a `InterruptedException` throwed by `SECONDS.sleep(1)`, the succeeding codes(`generator.cancel()` and `return generator.get()`) wouldn't be executed?

Comment: `generator.get()` wouldn't get executed in either case.